# Blind Estimation of Signal Parameters for Zero mean Normal distribution

Tags: gaussian, maximum-likelihood-estimation

Let $\mathbb{s}$ be zero mean with a normal distribution. Let one of the observed set of signals be given by $K\mathbb{s}$ and another by $L\mathbb{s^*}$, where $K$ and $L$ both are constants, and $\mathbb{s^*}$ is defined by complex conjugate of $\mathbb{s}$. Also the values of $KL$, $\mid K\mid$, $\mid L\mid$ are known, along with the known relation that $\mid K\mid^2 + \mid L\mid^2=1$.

Is there a way to estimate parameters $K$ and $L$? I tried solving non-linear set of equations, splitting real and imaginary terms of products $K\mathbb{s}$, $L\mathbb{s^*}$, however the system of equations seems to be underdetermined.

The set of equations by separating real and imaginary parts, I tried to solve were as follows:
$$ 
K_{re}s_{re}-K_{im}s_{im} = A\\
K_{re}s_{im}+K_{im}s_{re} = B\\
L_{re}s_{re}+L_{im}s_{im} = C\\
-L_{re}s_{im}+L_{im}s_{re} = D\\
K_{re}L_{re} - K_{im}L_{im} = E\\
K_{re}L_{im} + K_{im}L_{re} = F
$$
where $A$ & $B$ are the real & imaginary parts of $K\mathbb{s}$ respectively,  $C$ & $D$ are the real & imaginary parts of $K\mathbb{s}^*$ respetively and  $E$ & $F$ are the real & imaginary parts of $KL$ respectively.

After substitutions, I had following set of equations:
$$
s_{re}=\frac{CL_{re}+DL_{im}}{|L|^2}=\frac{AK_{re}+BK_{im}}{|K|^2}\\
s_{im}=\frac{CL_{im}-DL_{re}}{|L|^2}=\frac{BK_{re}-AK_{im}}{|K|^2}
$$
and got the relations between real & imaginary parts of $L$ and $K$ as follows:
$$
L_{re}=\frac{FK_{im}+EK_{re}}{|K|^2}\\
L_{im}=\frac{FK_{re}-EK_{im}}{|K|^2}
$$
However, I could not find a way forward to estimate $K$ and $L$, as further substitutions could not give me unique solutions for the parameters.
I hope someone has a better idea to attack the problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mention that you attempted the problem, can you include those steps in your question? That will help

Comment: @Engineer Thank you for having a look, I have added the steps which I tried.

Comment: @Andrew: Hi. I don't have time to think about it a lot but you may have variance relations also because  Ks is  normal with zero mean and variance K^2. This of course assumes that the variance of s = 1. If it is also unknown, then disregard my noise and no pun intended.

Comment: @markleeds Unfortunately, the variance of s is unknown, thanks for your time!

Comment: Hi Andrew:: Ok but  maybe it can give you some more equations since the variance of $K s =  K ^2 s ^ 2 $.

Comment: @markleeds I think variance should not give any new information because we are already aware of $|K|$ and $|L|$, and variance strips away the phase information. What would be helpful is if we can determine phases on $K$ and $L$, as  magnitudes are already known.

Comment: Okay. you know this stuff way better than me but I'm just making sure that you can't take the first equation and do,  $K_{re}^2 s_{re}^2 + K_{im}^2 s_{im}^2  = A^2$.

Comment: Is the data a vector or scalar?